# I am trying to let my discord webhook send message with buttons

Tags: javascript, json, discord, webhooks

So here is my problem.

I am trying to send messages via a discord webhook with buttons in but they don't display or sometimes just give an error code.

The error code basicly says that my JSON stringicicator does not function because of a syntrax error, which is weird because if i send a message without any button components it does function with no problem.

Here is my code:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/* the url of the bot */");

request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

const params = {
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "test",
      "description": "test",
      "color": 65474
    }
  ],
  "components": [
    {
      "type": 1,
      "components": [
        {
          "type": 2,
          "style": 5,
          "label": "kaas",
          "url": "/* url website */"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]


request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` to close the `params` object.

Comment: This did remove the error but the button still does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

## Your app needs to own the webhook

To send components, like buttons, your application needs to own the webhook

### What does owning a webhook mean?

it basically means you need a bot

### Why does discord not respond with an error?

this seems to be an issue, with discord, that they won't show an error if you send a non-application owned webhook with components. they have decided to just ignore it, you can see this [issue](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/5744)